# Vim command line bigger when tagbar is open

Tags: vim-windows, original-vim, plugin-tagbar

Vim's command line is bigger when TagBar is opened.

I am using windows terminal but this happens in Command Prompt as well.

What am I doing wrong? Or is there an option that I missed?

[image: command line starts mid-way through screen]

Comment: check the cmdheight and lines option values